# How to store sklearn Pipelines in a dictionary?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit various Pipelines and store them in a dictionary, but whenever I call a particular model from the dictionary it always returns the last Pipeline. How do I store the Pipelines in the dictionary correctly?

```
for var in vars:

    X = X_train[X_train.columns[X_train.columns.str.contains(var)]]
    y = Y_train[var] 

    pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler), ('clf', classifier)])
    models[var] = [X.columns,pipe.fit(X,y)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General way to store models in a dictionay:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import svm

X = [some features]
y = [some labels]

models_dictionary = {}
clf_1 = LinearRegression()
clf_2 = svm.SVR()

models_dictionary["Linear_Regression"] = clf_1
models_dictionary["Support_Vector _Machine"] = clf_2 

# training all models:
for model in models_dictionary:
    models_dictionay[model].fit(X, y)
```

your code:

`pipe.fit(X,y)` is an in-place function, that is where your problem is coming from.

instead of this line:

```py
models[var] = [X.columns,pipe.fit(X,y)]
```

use this:

```py
pipe.fit(X,y)
models[var] = [X.columns,pipe]
```

because `pipe.fit(X,y)` does not return a model, it just fits the Pipeline stored in `pipe`.

then you will be able to use any pipeline to predict values directly from `models`, doing this:

```py
y_predictions = models[some_var][1].predict(X_test)
```

Comment: That does not help either.

Comment: What is the issue exactly ?

Comment: Even when I change the code to what you suggest, the last model is stored in all the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: The model won't change as you already training the same pipeline, you are only changing X and y

Comment: I want to store different models based on the variable vars in my question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a general way of how you would do what you are seeking, hope its helps.